# send customized response from connexion flask server when token authorization fails

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, authorization, connexion

Before every endpoint is hit, token is authorized. I have created app same as below

```py
os.environ[TOKENINFO_FUNC] =  some_function
add.api(openapi.yaml)
app.add_error_handler(OAuthResponseProblem, render_unauthorized)

def render_unauthorized:
  return customized response 
def some_function:
  raise OAuthResponseProblem
```

is this the right way to hook the exceptions ? I am receiving errors for above code. here render_unauthorized is not getting invoked. I want to validate the tokens and send the endpoint user customized response. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need implement the `x-tokenInfoFunc`. In your function you can send a customized response.

- Documentation :
  https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#oauth-2-authentication-and-authorization
- Example :
  https://github.com/zalando/connexion/tree/master/examples/swagger2/oauth2

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if it's too late. I have faced the same issue. All what you need to do is to raise Unauthorized exception with your custom string.

```
import jwt    
from werkzeug.exceptions import Unauthorized    

# This is your TOKENINFO_FUNC
def decode_token(jwt_token):
  try:
    payload = jwt.decode(jwt_token, 'SECRET_KEY', algorithms=['HS256'])
    return payload
  except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
    raise Unauthorized('Token expired. Please log in again.')
  except jwt.InvalidTokenError:
    raise Unauthorized('Invalid token. Please log in again.')
```